# android - assigning shared uid to 2 apps

Tags: android

I am trying to run some tests wherein I need two apps written in Android Studio to have same uid when run in genymotion VM. I want to use the shareduid.

In both apps, I specify in the manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.android.my.app"
   android:sharedUserId="com.mytest">
```

However, this value of shared uid causes error when I try to run the application in genymotion. I referred other SO answers and see developers using a string value in sharedUserId field.

What am I missing ?

Comment: What kind of error do you get in Genymotion?

Comment: All apps which share the same userid should be signed with the same cert.

Comment: @HansKratz : Android Studio says : Session app - error.

Comment: @Jake What is the output if you try to install the apk from the commandline? Is anything logged via logcat?

Comment: @HansKratz there is no log. Just the 'Session app - error' in red color. If I removed android:sharedUserId, then app runs as normal.

Comment: Try installing the APK via adb install <path to apk> on the commandline to get a proper error message.

Comment: @HansKratz app apk installs fine using adb.

Comment: And running it on the device works fine as well after installing it this way?

Comment: @HansKratz yes it works fine via adb

Answer (score 0):

I had the two apps installed previously on genymotion, when I tested them through Android Studio. To use shared user id, I uninstalled both apps from Genymotion, and then ran them again from Android Studio. They worked as expected.